# Migration from Hibernate 4 to 5 and foreign keys with hbm2ddl.auto set to update

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I'm migrating my application from Hibernate 4 to 5.
When I set the hibernate property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`to `update` (needed to make the envers work) I receive a bunch of errors saying:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'FKdpu5x5cwbvck72kxs323m271e' in the database.
```

Since almost 6 months `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set to `update`, I've restored the db many times and never had this problem.

I tried to remove all the FK, but hibernate also complains about tables and PK. I already tried a different naming strategy, but it does not work.

I'm using hibernate 5.2.8.Final

Comment: Why must you use `update` here if all you're doing is migrating from Hibernate 4 to 5?  The schema should be fine, no need to `update`.  You simply need to configure the right settings that are appropriate based on the migration guides such as disabling new id generators, etc.

Comment: You're right, but I still don't understand why hibernate wants to add already existing FKs